# KVM virtualization erratic mouse for Windows Server

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm

This solves the problem with erratic mouse movement after virtualizing Windows including Server on KVM (Kernal based Virtual Machie).  After several days of trying every hint on the Internet, tweaks, different mouse drivers, I found a simple solution so I would like to make it available here:

Install Spice tools (Spice-Space.org downloads for Guest.) 
Here's the link: 
https://www.spice-space.org/download/windows/spice-guest-tools/spice-guest-tools-latest.exe

Comment: Of course we should move this question to the proper area, I'm not sure which area that would be, so I'll let a more knowledgeable person do that if you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer's in the question.  The Spice tools add various drivers to make the Windows virtual machine work properly including the mouse.  It is similar to VMware's tools that do a similar thing.